# Self referential association problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have the next models:

```
create_table :categories do |t|
  t.integer :category_id
  t.integer :language_id
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :category_localizated_categories, :force => true do |t|
  t.column :category_id, :integer
  t.column :localizated_category_id, :integer
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_localizated_categories
  has_many :localizated_categories, :through => :category_localizated_categories
end

class CategoryLocalizatedCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :localizated_category
end
```

I can do:

```
category1 = Category.create :language_id => 1
category2 = category1.localizated_categories.create :language_id => 2
```

And 2 categories are created in DB, but the association is not created:

```
category.localizated_categories
[]
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you go for a simpler self-referential association?

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :base_category, :class_name => "Category"
  has_many :localized_categories, :class_name => "Category", :inverse_of => :base_category

  scope :base, where(:base_category_id => nil)
  scope :localized, where("base_category_id NOT NULL")
  …
end
```

Comment: The model category would need two atributes for this relation, category_id and base_category_id, am I wrong?

Comment: No, you just need `base_category_id` in this case. I just named it that way to be more self explanatory but it is just as good to name the association `belongs_to :category` and the field `category_id`

Comment: Calling category.base generates the next SQL sentence:


 SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE (`categories`.category_id = 13) AND (`categories`.`category_id` IS NULL) ORDER BY `order` LIMIT 1

It has no sense... why?

The relations:
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :localized_categories, :class_name => "Category", :inverse_of => :category

  scope :base, where(:category_id => nil)
  scope :localized, where("category_id IS NOT NULL")

Comment: Are you calling `base` on the class `Category` or the association `category`? It should work as `Category.base` but become pointless as `@some_category.category.base`

Comment: Ok, I had to explicit set the foreign key:

  has_many :localized_categories, :class_name => "Category", :inverse_of => :base_category, :foreign_key => "base_category_id"

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_localizated_categories
  has_many :localizated_categories, :through => :category_localizated_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_localizated_categories
end
```

i think you need nested models here:

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Comment: But I can't even do: category1.localizated_categories << category2, it doesn't creates the association neither.